# Can't widen Bootstrap form controls

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to adjust the width of controls on a form when viewed on desktop and I can seem to get it right. I have tried `col-xs-12` and `style="width:100%";` -- neither made a difference. I can see when I inspect the element the `div` around the control seem to be the full width of the screen.

You can view the source of this page to see the problem, it is the title and description field I would like to be wider:  http://allthings.trade/poultry/farmingbooks/newpost

As you can see the footer is fine and the image selection is fine.

I have also cut the form right down in the sample below:

```
<form action="/poultry/edit" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <div class="validation-summary-valid" data-valmsg-summary="true">
        <ul>
            <li style="display:none"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Title">Title</label>
            <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Please enter a title" id="Title" name="Title" type="text" value="" />
            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `input` fields have a `max-width` declared.

```
input, select, textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
```

Once you adjust or remove that rule, you can expand your input fields.

Comment: It actually seems to be declared twice. Hard to tell exactly where since the CSS is compressed.

Comment: You can pinpoint its location using Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: You can see that it's in the compressed file (which is on line 1--everything is on line 1). You can't tell where it is in the original files.

Comment: It's a huge file. But I just pasted it into Notepad++. Ran a CTRL-F for "280", and it came up -- once.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a max-width in your css that is stopping the inputs from getting wider `input,select,textarea{/* max-width:280px */}`

Either override this with something like `input.some-class{max-width:100%}`, or remove the original css that is putting in the max-width.

Comment: Thanks heaps everyone. That was it